# Turning a compressed csv saved to a given url into a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have a given URL as a string and I'm trying to write a method that takes that 'URL string' and turns it first into a Pandas DataFrame and ultimately into a parquet file.

Behind the URL is a */loremipsum.csv.zip* file

this is what I tried so far

```
def save_csv_as_parquet(self, current_url):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(current_url)
    df = pd.read_csv(zf)
    df.to_parquet('events.parquet')
```

Comment: [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can accept a URL as the first parameter. URLs must have a host, so if it's a local file it should be given as something like `file://localhost/path/to/table.csv`. In principle, `pd.read_csv(current_url).to_parquet("events.parquet")` should work.

Comment: Even if it is not directly a csv file but a zipped csv file ?

Comment: i'm getting  following error ```File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 5```

Comment: The error that you are seeing is a problem with your input file. You can try adding `error_bad_lines=False` to the `read_csv` call. Or if you're using pandas >1.3.0 use `on_bad_lines="skip"`

Comment: but isn't it a Problem to just drop the columns ? how does Pandas determine how many Fields is the right amount ? can't i have the csv with missing values instead of dropping it entirely with ```error_bad_lines =False```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to download the zip file first and the use it in `zipfile.ZipFile()`, also you have not extracted it:

```
import urllib.request

def save_csv_as_parquet(self, current_url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(current_url, "loremipsum.csv.zip")
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("loremipsum.csv.zip")
    zf.extractall()
    df = pd.read_csv("loremipsum.csv")
    df.to_parquet('events.parquet')
```

Comment: it worked without using zipfle at all is that a Problem or can that cause Problems ??

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can accept a URL as the first parameter. URLs must have a host, so if it's a local file it should be given as something like file://localhost/path/to/table.csv. You should be able to stream line this into a single line:

```py
class Example:
    def save_csv_as_parquet(
        self,
        current_url, 
        output_file, 
        read_kws=None, 
        write_kws=None,
    ):
        read_kws = {} if read_kws is None else read_kws
        write_kws = {} if write_kws is None else write_kws
        pd.read_csv(current_url, **read_kws).to_parquet(output_file, **write_kws)

e = Example()
e.save_csv_as_parquet(
    "https://.../file.csv.zip", 
    "events.parquet", 
    read_kws= {"on_bad_lines": "skip"},
)
```

I've added some extra parameters so you can specify the output file and extra keyword arguments that are passed to the read/write functions.

Let me know if you have any questions.